# Order and sort result mysql or using php array funciton

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "student_points".

```
id    user_id     points   subject_id      
 1      10         45           22
 2      11         75           23
 3      12         78           24
 4      10         13           23
 5      12         65           23
```

and so on ...

This table contain about 1000 records of users and points.
I want 10 records based on points (Max points first)
So I can use mysql query as

```
Select * from student_points order by points limit 0,10
```

Now the requirement is that we need to group these 10 records based on user_id
For example in first 10 records three are 3 students records so they should display in group.
End result should be like

```
   id    user_id     points    subject_id  
    3      12         78           24
    5      12         65           23
    1      10         45           22
    4      10         13           23
    2      11         75           23
```

You can see that first record is based on most point and it student id is 12, now they are group according to user_id.

I tried two order by .
I also tried to array_multisort after getting result but both are not working properly.

Please suggest any way, Either mysql query or group after getting result.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want 10 records for each `user_id` sorted by descending order of points?

Comment: ORDER BY user_id DESC, points DESC?

Comment: you want to sum up the points as well, right?

Comment: What would be final result you want ?

Comment: Hello , I edited question for better understanding , now there is subject_id. those 10 results there can be records of  3 students based on points in different subject , I just want to group them based on user_id .

Comment: If user group is large then it should be first. Can u tell me what if `user_id` = `10` is 3 times

Answer (score 1):

This should work just add a limit to whatever number you want to limit by

```
select sp.id, sp.user_id, sp.points 
from student_points sp
join (select user_id, max(points) as sort_by from student_points group by user_id) sort_table on sp.user_id = sort_table.user_id
order by sort_table.sort_by desc, sp.user_id, sp.points desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your required result I have written the query :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Select * from student_points order by points limit 0,10
) As st
GROUP BY user_id,subject_id
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Please try this. Let me know if this is not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to wrap up your query in  a subquery and later sort the results based on `user_id` and `points`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  Select * from student_points order by points limit 0,10
) AS t
ORDER BY 
  t.user_id DESC, 
  t.points DESC
```

Comment: I would love to hear the reason behind **downvoting**

Comment: @1000111  , Hello please read question again, I have edited .

Comment: Your requirement can still be achieved by this query. Please give this a try and let me know @Rich5757

Comment: This will not show the student ID / group with the highest score first, so the conditions are not met completely.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. Actually I didn't get your message. Would you please post an answer here @jeroen

Comment: @1000111  Hi I am checking , I will let you know.

Comment: I think you need to do something like @JohnHarrison is doing as now it works because the highest `user_id` has the highest points. But that is a coincidence so ordering by `user_id` does not automatically get the user with the highest score on top.